# assignment/update of a list in Haskell (speed is considered)

Tags: haskell

I want to implement the following Python code in Haskell. Similar article has been found in stack overflow, but I found they are too slow.

python:

```
for k in s:
    a[k] = False
```

haskell:

```
setfalse s a = over (elements (`elem` s)) (const False) a
```

or more natively

```
setfalse [] a = a
setfalse _ [] = []
setfalse (0:is) (a:as) = False : (setfalse ((\x->(x-1)) <$> is) as)
setfalse s (a:as) = a : (setfalse ((\x->(x-1)) <$> s) as)
```

Do you have a faster implementation?

I constructed the problem when I tried to implement `sieve of Eratosthenes`

Comment: Where exactly did you find this answer? Do you understand what it is doing? Creating an (infinte) list of `False`s, is just `repeat False`. Furthermore since Haskell is a declarative language, you can just "update" a value, in fact all variables are, once assigned, constant.

Comment: @Willem this code (the second fragment anyway, have no idea how the first one works) does more or less what the Python code does, modulo non-destructive nature of Haskell. Namely it goes over a list of *indices* and then replaces corresponding elements in another list with `False`. Why do you think `repeat False` is relevant here?

Comment: @n.m.: ah, I somehow had the idea that we ranged over *all* indices. Thanks.

Comment: Try [this](https://ideone.com/ZgwbLb) though I doubt it will bring any significant speed up (can't check it myself with my phone).

Comment: If you want a mutable array in Haskell why would you use an immutable linked list?  use the `array` or `vector` package and the structures provided therein.

Comment: @n.m. thank you for your help and thank Willem too.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that `s` is strictly increasing (and still want to use an immutable list) then you can do the following:

```
setFalse is xs = go is xs 0 where
  go [] xs _ = xs
  go _ [] _= error “index out of bounds”
  go is@(i:is') (x:xs) n | i <= n = False : go is' xs (1+n)
                         | otherwise = x : go is xs
```

Comment: but, is that fast?

Comment: It’s linear. Specifically if `is` has maximum element m and `xs` has length n, the complexity is O(min(m,n)). If you want something fast then updating immutable lists is entirely wrong.